# How to split Service/Controller layer classes into interface and impl?

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have the following controller class in my Spring boot project, split into interface and implementation:

```
public interface UserAccountController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String login(@RequestBody UserAccountEntity account,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/signup", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String create(@Valid @RequestBody UserAccountEntity userAccount,
            HttpServletResponse response, BindingResult result);

}

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/authentication")
public class UserAccountControllerImpl implements UserAccountController {

    @Autowired
    private UserAccountService userAccountService;

    @Override
    public String login(@Valid @RequestBody UserAccountEntity account,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
            //...
    }

    @Override
    public String create(@Valid @RequestBody UserAccountEntity userAccount,
            HttpServletResponse response, BindingResult result) {
            //....
    }
}
```

When I move RestController and RequestMapping annotations to the interface, it doesn't work. But annotating the methods on the interface work. How are these two annotations different?

Answer (score 1):

`@RestController` inherits from `@Controller`, which inherits from @Component thus leading to the creation of a Spring Bean in your application context.

`@RequestMapping` inherits from `@Mapper` and is used to mark Rest- or Web-Controller methods as handler methods.

As to why Spring is implemented to disallow inheritance on the first and allow it on the second, I can only speculate:

- I think your example constitutes a useful usecase for `@Mapping` inheritance, since you could have several RestControllers with different url prefixes, but other than that the same endpoints.
- Making `@Component` annotations inheritable could lead to involuntarily created Spring Beans, since clients might fail to notice the annotation when implementing the interface.